# Delay in request call response body

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I am making a request rest call to.spring boot API from bot framework . Based on response I need to send context . But the API response is delayed and the if block below the request call is running .

Comment: Here is the guide line for "How to ask a proper queston" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , Please elaborate the ASK clearly.

Comment: Are you using BotBuilder V3 or V4?

Comment: V4 i am using . Building bot with node js

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to await your API calls. You have a few [options](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/http-requests-node-js-async-await/) when it comes to asynchronous HTTP libraries for Node, but Axios is generally recommended.

[Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/asynchronous-javascript-using-async-await) is a nice tutorial involving async/await and Axios. Example:

```
async function asyncFunc() {
  // fetch data from a url endpoint
  const response = await axios.get("/some_url_endpoint");
  const data = await response.json();

  return data;
}
```

Comment: After getting the data from json response , when i am sending the data into prompt, i am getting an error " [onTurnError]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". If i declare local array with some default values, this issue is not coming.

Comment: Did you already address that issue in a new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550764/cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-error-in-bot-framework